# Data Restriction on JavaScript Form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a specific date restriction on a form - no entry dates prior to the year 2016. I have input the following:

```
if (!VALIDATING) {
  if (myStartDTYear > 2016 || (myStartDT > myREPORTEDDT)) {
    alert("Please, valid date with year 2016 or later, prior to reported date");
    # STARTDT.setValue(null);
  }
  if (mySTOPDT.getFullYear() > 2016) {
    alert("Please, date with year 2016 or later");
    # STOPDT.setValue(null);
  }
  if (myREPORTEDDT.getFullYear() > 2016 || (mySTOPDT > todayDate)) {
    alert("Please, valid date with year 2016 or later, today or prior is required!");
    # REPORTEDDT.setValue(null);
  }
  if (myHOSPSTDT.getFullYear() > 2016) {
    alert("The Hospital admission date year should be 2016 , today or prior");
    # HOSPSTDT.setValue(null);
  }
  if (myHOSPENDT.getFullYear() > 2016) {
    alert("Hospital discharge date year should be 2016 , today or prior");
    # HOSPENDT.setValue(null);
  }
}
```

But on entry, I can still enter in a date from 2015 in the myStartDTYear variable section.

Comment: Which language is that? `#` is not used in JavaScript.

Comment: Which rule do you think is going to exclude a `myStartDTYear` or 2015? Are you perhaps confusing `<` with `>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `min` attribute in your [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

```
<input type="date" min="2016-01-01">
```

But as always keep in mind that a malicious user will be able to circumvent any client-side restrictions so check the value on the server too.

It also seems that you are inverting the `greater than` with `lesser than` operator, currently you are throwing alerts if `date is greater than 2016`. Change the conditions to:

```
  myHOSPSTDT.getFullYear() < 2016
```

Comment: Perfect! In my head, I read that the could would include dates only greater than the date, but should have read the code as exclusionary. Thanks!